# http://localhost:8080 not working in windows 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have installed IIS 7 in my PC which runs windows 7. When I and type `http://localhost:8080` I am not getting the IIS home page. I tried in IE, Google Chrome and mozilla firefox. In all the browsers I am getting a `page 404 error`. I don't know what to do.

I have tried the following steps for resolution:

1. Removed the `#` symbol from the host file under the system 32 directory
2. Stopped and restarted the IIS
3. When I type inetmgr in the run command, the IIS window opens up but I am not getting the default website node.
4. When I navigate to `c:\windows\inetpub\wwwroot`, I am not able to see the default website directory.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you install IIS on your machine it doesn't listen on 8080, it listens on 80

*edit*

The default site is located in c:\inetpub\wwwroot, never in the windows directory